# Docker container with multiple outgoing IPs

Tags: linux, docker, networking

I have an application written in node js which is using multiple outgoing IPs to make requests to website. Basically, I want to make requests to some website with different IPs, which I have assigned to my VPS. I want to containerize my application with docker, but docker only has access to the main IP from the host machine and I was not able to assign my other IPs to that container. I've tried many things and been stuck on that problem for days...

```
  IPv4 address for enp1s0:          xxx.xx.xxx.70
  IPv4 address for enp1s0:          xxx.xxx.x.145
  IPv4 address for enp1s0:          xxx.xxx.xxx.154
```

I need to be able to select one of these IPs from node js application inside docker container and me an HTTP request with it.

Also if what I said is not possible it is also acceptable to assign each IP to each container (so 3 containers in total with different outgoing IPs). But this is not ideal. I'm looking for a painless way of doing this since I want to be able to pre-configure my apps and docker-compose to automate most of this work.

Comment: Have you tried to run docker with `--network host` ?

Comment: @Philippe Yes. That works but as I read doing it that way there will be some security risks and I don't want that.